How to fetch author information in Shopify GraphQL admin API for events?
Shopify rest admin api for events used to have author information in the response which is not present in its equivalent graphQL api. How to get author information ?
Am I missing any node ? The API doc doesn't provide any further information.
Rest Admin API response

GraphQL API request

GraphQL API response

